# Examples of inner product on the space of continous functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

Let $C([a,b], \mathbb{R})$ be the space of continous functions $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. I am looking for examples of inner products on this space. I know the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b fg$ which can be generalized to $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b fgh$ where $h \in C([a,b], \mathbb{R})$ is a non negative function. I haven't been able to find more examples for the space of continuous functions. I'd be especially interested in an inner product that doesn't depend on integration. Does anyone know more examples or a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you need $h$ to be a positive function. Do you know some examples on the space of polynomials of degree $\le n$?

Comment: In the space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$ we can use the dot product applied to the coefficients. If $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ and $q(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n   b_ix^i$ then $\langle p, q \rangle = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ib_i $ is an inner product. I guess this can be generalized to any subspace of finite dimension but im not sure if it can be generalized to the whole space.

Comment: Well, that's just using the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. I had in mind something more interesting, using values at $n+1$ arbitrary points of the interval. But it still won't generalize to all continuous functions. You can probably do some sort of horrible construction using the fact (Stone-Weierstrass) that all polynomials are dense in $C([a,b],\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Let $(r_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[a,b]$ and set $\langle f,g \rangle= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(r_n)g(r_n)/2^n$.

Comment: @Gerd +1 I should have thought of that. You should post that as an answer. The OP should check all the details. :)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(r_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be an enumeration of $[a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ (or, more general, a dense sequence in $[a,b]$) and let $(c_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be any sequence in $(0, \infty)$ with $\sum_{n \ge 1} c_n < \infty$. Then, check that
$$
\langle f,g \rangle := \sum_{n \ge 1} c_nf(r_n)g(r_n)
$$
is an inner product on $C([a,b], \mathbb{R})$.